# OpenSSL 1.1.1e RC4-MD5 cipher not getting selected for TLS v1.2

Tags: c, openssl, libcurl, libssl

i have been facing this issue where i cant send RC4-MD5 cipher in Client hello tls protocol layer.
my current code uses curl SSL CTX CALLBACK.

you can see my code below....nothing fancy here but the last cipher does not go in the client hello
my tls protocols are http1.0, tlsv1.2, i compiled openssl with option for weak ciphers(and it works for DES cipher)

```
 CURLcode sslctxfun(CURL *curl, void *sslctx, void *parm)
{
  sslctxparm *p = (sslctxparm *) parm;
  SSL_CTX *ctx = (SSL_CTX *) sslctx;

  int ret;
  SSL_CTX_set_max_proto_version(ctx, TLS1_2_VERSION);
  SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version(ctx, TLS1_2_VERSION);
  ret=SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "AES256-SHA256,AES128-SHA256,AES256-SHA,AES128-SHA,DES-CBC3-SHA,RC4-SHA,RC4-MD5");
.....
  SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_ALL);
  SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_TICKET);
  SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_ENCRYPT_THEN_MAC);
  SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE);
  SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx,SSL_OP_NO_RENEGOTIATION);
  SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_TLS_ROLLBACK_BUG );
  SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_DONT_INSERT_EMPTY_FRAGMENTS );
  SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION );
  SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT );
  SSL_CONF_CTX *cctx;
  cctx = SSL_CONF_CTX_new();
  SSL_CONF_CTX_set_flags(cctx, SSL_CONF_FLAG_FILE);
  SSL_CONF_CTX_set_ssl_ctx(cctx, ctx);
  ret=SSL_CONF_cmd(cctx, "SignatureAlgorithms", "RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA1");
....
}
```

Comment: This code is not complete.  Are you running as the server or the client?  Does the peer you're connecting to support RC4-MD5 ciphers?

Comment: I’m a client. The server expects a 1-1 packet of client hello. In which client hello should respond that rc4-md5 is supported by client and ssl3/tls standards do acknowledge that. The rest of the code which is url and post data is handled by libcurl. A simple look at the packet shows me that rc4-md5 is not being sent as supported cipher by client(me)

Answer (score 1):

That ciphersuite is not available in the default OpenSSL security level (which is level 1). You need to instruct it to use security level 0. One way to do that is to add `,@SECLEVEL=0` onto the end of your ciphersuite list:

```
ret=SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "AES256-SHA256,AES128-SHA256,AES256-SHA,AES128-SHA,DES-CBC3-SHA,RC4-SHA,RC4-MD5,@SECLEVEL=0");
```

Alternatively you can set it using `SSL_CTX_set_security_level()`. See the man page for a description of the levels:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_security_level.html

Comment: This sounds like the topic of a separate question!